# .NET Excel Interop Worksheet.Copy failing after 255 sheets

Tags: .net, excel-interop

Got a question that I've found only rarely asked, and seen no good responses for.

Very simple piece of code, in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Data
```

`Imports System.IO`

`Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`

```
Dim anExcelApplicationClass As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    anExcelApplicationClass = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    anExcelApplicationClass.Visible = False
    anExcelApplicationClass.UserControl = False
    anExcelApplicationClass.DisplayAlerts = False
    anExcelApplicationClass.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim devWorkbooks As Workbooks
    Dim devWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim masterTempWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim tempWorksheet As Worksheet

    devWorkbooks = anExcelApplicationClass.Workbooks
    devWorkbook = devWorkbooks.Open(DevFilePath, 0, False, 5, "", "", False, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", True, False, 0, True, False, False)

    Dim tempCounter As Integer = 0
    While tempCounter < 500
        tempCounter = tempCounter + 1
        masterTempWorksheet.Copy(Type.Missing, masterTempWorksheet)
        tempWorksheet = CType(devWorkbook.Sheets(3), Worksheet)
        tempWorksheet.Name = tempCounter.ToString()
    End While
```

For me, after 255 iterations, the code fails with a rather useless error of "Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC".

From research, I've seen some people saying this is the limit of the number of worksheets, but I've seen others suggesting that there is no real limit, and that the actual limit is simply based on your system.

Note: I tried saving and closing, then re-opening the worksheet after some iterations, as suggested in here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684/en-us. It did not solve the problem.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684

Comment: As I said, I tried that solution, and it did not help.

Comment: Actually I guess I spoke too soon. I did test it, but then after your comment, I re-tested it just to be sure. I guess that I didn't test right, because on the re-test, it turned out to work fine. So I guess I'll mark yours as the answer once I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necro-ing this thread just to post it as answered - the solution is to save, close, and re-open the worksheet, as suggested at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684/en-us, and by @HansPassant.

Although, I've since moved on towards a better solution, using OpenXML instead of the Interop library, so if anyone finds this question, I'd suggest a better answer would be to consult the OpenXML SDK, documentation for which can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx